# Как в режиме runtime считать по новому app config

Tags: c#, config

Здравствуйте столкнулся с такой проблемой, у меня есть такой конфиг

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name ="watcherSettings" type ="ConfigurationManager.WatcherSettings.WatcherSection, ConfigurationManager"/>
    </configSections>
    <watcherSettings>
        <sender name="oleg" email="oleg-ba2000@yandex.ru" password="connected123232" mailClient="smtp.yandex.ru"/>
        <targets>
            <target checkInterval ="5" responseTime ="3"  url ="https://vk.com" email ="jktubabichev@yandex.ru"></target>
        </targets>
    </watcherSettings>
</configuration>
```

Вот такой код для считывания конфигурации

```
public void RefreshConfig()
{

    System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("targets");
}

private WatcherSection GetWatcherSection()
{
    RefreshConfig();
    var cfg = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("WatcherSite.dll");
    return (WatcherSection)cfg.GetSection("watcherSettings");
}
```

С помощью FileWatcher слежу за этим конфигом при изменение пытаюсь перечитать но приходят старые значения

```
public Watcher(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    //Конструктор
    _configuration = configuration ?? throw new NullReferenceException(nameof(configuration));
    _configuration.RefreshConfig();
    _targets = _configuration.ReadTargetsFromConfig();
    _emailSender = _configuration.ReadEmailSenderFromConfig();
    pathToConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None).FilePath;

    var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToConfig);
    _fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(path)
    {
        EnableRaisingEvents = true,
        IncludeSubdirectories = true,
        Filters = { "*.config" }
    };

    _fileSystemWatcher.Changed += OnChanged;
    _fileSystemWatcher.Created += OnChanged;

    BeginWork("Watcher start working");
}

private void RefreshSettings()
{
    foreach (var target in _targets)
    {
        target.Dispose();
    }
    Logger = LogManager.GetLogger("file");
    _targets = _configuration.ReadTargetsFromConfig();
    _emailSender = _configuration.ReadEmailSenderFromConfig();
    BeginWork("Watcher settings is refreshed and continiue working with new params");
}
```

Comment: Можете привести полный код FileWatcher?

Comment: У вас нет метода `OnChanged`. Внутри `OnChanged` вы должны поместить всю логику рефреша вашей конфигурации.

Comment: `
private void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            RefreshSettings();
        }

     
`

Comment: Вам нужно внутри метода `RefreshSettings()` зарефрешить ваш конфиг (вызвать `RefreshConfig()`). Причем нужно зарефрешить секцию `watcherSettings`, если я не ошибаюсь, а не targets

Comment: Я так и делаю поместил логику рефреша

Comment: В вашем примере я не вижу явного вызова `RefreshConfig` внутри метода `RefreshSettings`